# ¿como puedo sustituir valores traidos en un query con php?

Tags: php

```
<php 

$connect =mysqli_connect("localhost"  ,"root" , "" , "helpdesk");
$query ="SELECT status, count(*) as number FROM ticket  GROUP BY status  ";
$results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);



while ($mostrar =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  # code...
?>

  <tr><td><?php echo $mostrar['total'] ?></td><td><?php echo $mostrar['status'] ?></td></tr>
</tbody>
<?php }?>
```

Tengo este código que me retorna bien la cuenta de los valores que tengo en una tabla y el estatus , sin embargo quiero cambiar mediante php los campos obtenidos donde se muestra el estatus por otros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero hacer algo como

```
if ($mostrar['status']=1){  $mostrar['status']= "pendiente por revisar";}
```

pero cuando lo hago , todos los campos campos se cambian a ese valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando mal el operador de comparación; recuerda que si usas:

1. un solo signo de igual `=` entonces asignas un valor
2. doble signo de igual `==` comparas un valor
3. Triple signo de igual `===` para comparar si son iguales y del mismo tipo los datos que estas comparando

Entonces esta línea debería quedar así

```
if ($mostrar['status']== 1)
{  
  $mostrar['status']= "pendiente por revisar";
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias (y) me quedo claro , esta es la respuesta que buscaba amigo

Comment: si, pero no puedo hacerlo hasta pasado 11 minutos (y) feliz día.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso te puedes evitar el `if`, usando un operador ternario.

```
<td>
    <?php echo ($mostrar['status']==1) ? "Pendiente por revisar" : $mostrar['status']; ?>
</td>
```

Y como sugerencia, yo evitaría la constante mezcla de código PHP/HTML, usando una variable de concatenación. El resultado será un código menos confuso y mucho más fácil de mantener o de portar a otra parte (imaginemos por ejemplo un escenario donde tengas que devolver la tabla a una Vista).

```
<?php 

    $connect =mysqli_connect("localhost"  ,"root" , "" , "helpdesk");
    $query ="SELECT status, count(*) as total FROM ticket GROUP BY status  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    /*Verificar si hubo resultados antes de intentar crear la tabla*/
    $html="<table>";
    $html.="<tbody>"; //Esto debería ir fuera del while
    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $total=$mostrar['total'];
        $status=($mostrar['status']==1) ? "Pendiente por revisar" : $mostrar['status'];
        $html.="<tr><td>$total</td><td>$status</td></tr>";
    }
    $html.="</tbody>";
    $html.="</table>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

> **NOTA SOBRE OPTIMIZACIÓN**:
>
> **He usado `mysqli_fetch_assoc` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array`**, porque este último te crea dos tipos de resultados por cada columna
>   (uno como array asociativo y otro como array numérico). Dado que sólo
>   te interesan los valores en forma de array asociativo, usa las
>   funciones/métodos más adecuadas a lo que necesites. Estarás manejando
>   un resultado menos pesado, en vez de 4 datos por fila manejarás 2. Si
>   la consulta produce 1000 filas, hablamos de que estarás descargando al servidor de 2000 datos menos. Siempre es importante tener en cuenta la
>   *optimización* del código.